# What measures have been taken to prevent something like the left-pad incident happening again?

Tags: javascript, npm, frontend, node-modules

In 2016, the maintainer of the left-pad package unpublished it from NPM, leaving millions of builds broken before NPM stepped in and un-unpublished the package themselves before too much chaos could arise

https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/

What preventative measures have been put in place against such incidents occurring in the future? Has anything changed in how `node_modules` files are managed locally, bundled, etc? Did NPM change their policy on how open-source works? Is there any expected effort to move away from or modify the way open-source development works to handle issues like these?

Edit: I was looking to generate open-ended discussion but I guess StackOverflow is not the place for that, so modified my question accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry but this question isn't really directly about programming. There will always be abuse vectors and usually when we look back on them we will say, "why didn't we think that could happen?" It becomes much more difficult to unpublished packages after 72 hours. That is likely due to this very issue. We cant predict what the next vector is. The answer is "yes" of course something could happen. Its opinion based though because we cant predict what or when it will be.

Comment: There might be safeguards against unpublishing heavily used packages, but I doubt any automated system could detect if a maintainer replaces a release with broken code (say, doing right-pad instead of left-pad)

Comment: To make the question more on-topic, I'd suggest specifically to ask "*What measures have been taken, what safeguards have been implemented, to prevent this from happening again?*" instead of the open-ended "*could something like this happen?*" or "*what's the worst that could possibly happen?*" questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## npm made it harder to unpublish packages

The incident occurred because the maintainer of `left-pad` was able to unpublish the package, despite the community’s dependency on it.

Shortly after the incident (March 23rd 2016), npm published a [post-mortem](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141577284765/kik-left-pad-and-npm.html) which included their plans for resolution:

> We will make it harder to un-publish a version of a package if doing so would break other packages.

npm soon followed up with an [update](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141905368000/changes-to-npms-unpublish-policy.html) (March 29th 2016):

> If the version is older than 24 hours, then the unpublish will fail, with a message to contact support@npmjs.com.

npm announced a more significant [update](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/190553543620/changes-to-npmunpublish-policy-january-2020.html) recently (January 2020), which is their currently effective [unpublish policy](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish):

> #### Packages published less than 72 hours ago
>
> For newly created packages,
> as long as no other packages in the npm Public Registry depend on your
> package, you can unpublish anytime within the first 72 hours after
> publishing.
>
> #### Packages published more than 72 hours ago
>
> Regardless of how long ago a
> package was published, you can unpublish a package that:
>
> - no other packages in the npm Public Registry depend on
> - had less than
>   300 downloads over the last week
> - has a single owner/maintainer

This means that a package such as `left-pad`, which many other packages depended on, effectively cannot be unpublished.

## npm blocked publishing to an abandoned package name

The other concern was that it was previously possible for someone to publish a malicious package to an abandoned package name (which luckily didn't happen in the case of `left-pad`). npm rectified this as part of their initial [post-mortem](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141577284765/kik-left-pad-and-npm.html):

> If a package with known dependents is completely unpublished, we’ll
> replace that package with a placeholder package that prevents
> immediate adoption of that name. It will still be possible to get the
> name of an abandoned package by contacting npm support.